# nginx: Redirect request with server having a dynamic ip

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https, configuration

I have a nginx server set up behind a router that gets a new ip-adress every day.

Now I want to redirect every user who accesses the site via

> http://[IP]/

to

> https://[IP]/

this works fine inside the local network, but if I access the site from outside it obviously doesn't.

Here's an extract from my nginx-configuration-file (/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/ ...)

```
server_name $hostname;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key
# redirect to HTTPS
if ($scheme = http) {
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

How can I make `server_name` change every day, when the public IP changes?
I can't use something like dyndns or noIP.

Is it even possible to change this during runtime without restarting nginx?

Comment: I know: The ssl-certificate can't be trusted, because the ip changes.
But this isn't important.

Comment: Problem solved with `crontab`